# Automate keystroke enter in curses with command from bash

Tags: automation, ncurses

I don't see any solution to my problem in the existing aricles,so guys please help

I want to automate installation so i'm using the 
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install 
the program that i want to install reqquires to install another program  which runs in ncurses and ask the user to press enter

I ve already tried the echo '\r\n' | sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install "mycommand"
But it didn't work

Comment: Usually the dialogs that are spawned during apt operations are from underlying dpkg configure / reconfigure commands - you can replace them with a simple readline CLI by setting `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline` - then you won't need to wrangle with ncurses

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i found that the easiest way to install a package ,with script ,that need confirmation (enter pressed) from the user.

First you have to find where you will echo the true value.
 Open a terminal and install the package, let's say  the package that you want to install is the oracle-java8-installer

1)"sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install oracle-java8-installer" (i used force yes so it don't ask for y/n)

Find the name of the parametre that need to be set true. 
2) "sudo debconf-show oracle-java8-installer" ,with this you ll see the parametres of the package . In this example the bash replies with:

shared/error-oracle-license-v1-1: 
* shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1: true 
  oracle-java8-installer/local:
  oracle-java8-installer/not_exist:
  shared/present-oracle-license-v1-1:

From the above list we need the "shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1" this is the parametre that sould be true.(now it's already true because the installation is done in this machine)

3)So now that you know the parametre, in the script you'll write:
echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections (for setting the value) 
and 
sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install oracle-java8-installer (to install)